# How to add a class to html tag?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML code like

```
<div class="class1 class2">
  <ul><li class="class1"></li></ul>
</div>
```

Here the div tag and the li tag have same class name, I just want to add another class to the li tag that have the class `class1`.
How can I do this?

Comment: not a valid html , `$('li.class1').addClass('class')`

Comment: use selector ex $('li').addClass('class')

Comment: As  Pranav C Balan said, your HTML is not valid

Comment: updated the html Pranav and Jurion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>First of all your markup is not valid</strike>

> The HTML `<li>` element (or HTML List Item Element) is used to represent an item in a list. It must be contained in a parent element: an ordered list (`<ol>`), an unordered list (`<ul>`), or a menu (`<menu>`).  ( Taken from : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li )

---

You can add class by using **[`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)**

```js
$('li.class1').addClass('class2');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
  <ul><li class="class1"></li></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @ShafeequeS : glad to help

Answer (score 1):

if You want to add class Dynamical use jquery :

```
<script>
$( "li.class1" ).addClass( "selected" );
</script>
```

[learn More](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)